# What is this shrub with fan shaped toothed leaves and small white blooms, and what are these small bugs?

Tags: identification, insects, shrubs

Can anyone help ID this shrub growing in Zone 6.

It's about 5' tall and 3' spread after pruning in the fall. It grows fairly fast.

Leaves sort of look like a fan leafed hawthorne to me but not quite.

Has clusters of small white blooms with yellow centers.

Today I noticed some green colored aphids on the stems. On the underside of leaves there were small gnat looking bugs. Any idea what the bugs on the undersides might have been? Dark colored bodies and large clear wings.

Other narrow, simple leaved shrubs in that vicinity were bug free.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spirea, probably Vanhouttei](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=c293), also called  the bridal wreath spirea. Yes, those are aphids on the stems but need a picture to id the other ones you mention

Edit: a positive ID would be the smell of the flowers which I would not describe as pleasant.  Almost a burnt smell?

Comment: That's it! I took the pics before I sprayed with neem. Didn't look under the leaves until I was spraying and didn't notice the winged bugs until I was done.